# How to use angular2_components

Tags: angular, dart, material-design

Can someone please tell me, how to use angular2_components? 
I've tried as follow:

```
<material-button>Test</material-button>
```

But it does not show a button as expected.

**Update**
What I did:

The pubspec yaml:

```
dependencies:
  angular2: ^2.0.0
  angular2_components: ^0.1.0
dev_dependencies:
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1
transformers:
- angular2:
    platform_directives:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_DIRECTIVES'
    platform_pipes:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_PIPES'
    entry_points: web/main.dart
```

the app_component.dart:

```
import 'package:angular2/core.dart';
import 'package:angular2_components/angular2_components.dart';

@Component(
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: const[
      MaterialButtonComponent,
    ],
    styleUrls: const ['app_component.css'],
    templateUrl: 'app_component.html')
class AppComponent {}
```

The the button still looks like:
[image]

and also got error messages:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you included required js/css files for angular2_components?

Comment: It is not in package included? How to get them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
dependencies:
  angular2_components: ^0.1.1
```

to your `pubspec.yaml` file and run `pub get`.

Then you need to import `MaterialButtonComponent`

```
import 'package:angular2_components/angular2_components.dart'
    show MaterialButtonComponent, materialProviders; // the show Xxx is optional
```

and then add it to `@Directives()` of the component where you want to use it

```
@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: const [
    MaterialButtonComponent,
  ],
  providers: [materialProviders],
  ...
)
```

For more details see https://dart-lang.github.io/angular2_components_example/
 and https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2_components_example/blob/master/lib/app_component.html

Comment: What are the benefits of explicitly typing the directives array as `dynamic`? Or do you need that in strong mode or something?

Comment: First of all, thanks you so much but what <dynamic> means?

Comment: That's not necessary, it is just a generic type parameter that specializes a list (`[a, b, c]`)  `<Abc>[]` to be a list of `Abc` (like `new List<Abc>()`) or with `<dynamic>` to be a list of everything. I have a linter rule enabled that enforces type annotations everywhere, but it's discouraged according to the Dart style guide to add too much type annotations and it's quite noisy. It was quite convenient when the analyzer wasn't yet as powerful as it is currently.

Comment: Right, for the ripple effect the `materialProviders` needs to be provided. I updated my answer.

Comment: No need to add CSS except for icons. For icons add `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">`

Comment: One more question, where do you know that? For what is `materialProviders` for?

Comment: Because I run into the same error and asked ;-) It's a global service used for the ripple effect.

Comment: Thanks you so much.